# How can I store my JWT token in userInfo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try a lot of things but I can´t go on .. I stucked ...
If I login in to my account it works I get also my userInfo but only userID and my password.. but I would have my token also ..

I wrote an if state where I catch my token but I want to set it also in the localStorage and I don´t know how to do it..

```
export const login = (userID, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST });
       
        const url = "http://localhost:8080/authenticate/";
        const config = {
          auth: {
            username: userID,
            password,
          },
        };
    
        const data = {};
        const response = await axios.post(
            url, 
            data, 
            config,
        )

        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: config});
        //localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(config) );
 
        if (response.status === 200) {
          // Login succeeded
          const token = response.data.token;
          console.log("TOKEN\n" + token);
          localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(config) );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        //alert("Sorry, login failed");
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
            payload:
                error.response && error.response.data.ErrorMessage
                    ? error.response.data.ErrorMessage
                    : error.message,
        });
      }
};
```

Comment: You're not adding the token to local storage anywhere. If you can do console.log(token) you can also `setItem('token',token)`

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm understanding the question, do you want to put the token inside of config, then store it in localstorage?

Comment: are you trying to store the token within the userinfo object?

Comment: @acbay yes I want to try this..

Comment: @qadirpervez If I can do it .. it would be great.

Comment: @JoaoLeal It doesn´t work .. I tried it

Comment: then set a property on userinfo inside your `if (response.status === 200) {` code block
and then after that block use this line
`localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(config) );`

Comment: but you should not save the password in your local storage

Comment: @qadirpervez it doesn´t work .. I show you what I have did what you told me..

Comment: I have answered it, you also have to attach the token inside your config object but please don't save your password in local storage

Comment: @basics_typer I guess you're confused by whether your request modify your authentication config or not. In my understanding, you are assuming that after the request succeed config will include the token, but its not:) I think you want to store something from your response.data actually.

Comment: @acbay .. qadirpervez solve it below :)

Comment: @basics_typer yes i'm aware, but still please think of what I said above. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
export const login = (userID, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST });
       
        const url = "http://localhost:8080/authenticate/";
        const config = {
          auth: {
            username: userID,
            password, //this should not be saved in your local storage delete this from here
          },
        };
    
        const data = {};
        const response = await axios.post(
            url, 
            data, 
            config,
        )

        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: config});
 
        if (response.status === 200) {
          // Login succeeded
          config.token = response.data.token;
          
        }
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(config) );
      } catch (error) {
        //alert("Sorry, login failed");
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
            payload:
                error.response && error.response.data.ErrorMessage
                    ? error.response.data.ErrorMessage
                    : error.message,
        });
      }
};
```

Comment: Wait I will try..

Comment: if you get the token inside your `response.data.token` then it should save it

Comment: It works thanks a lot .. :D 
Now I want to try to get my single Notes for this user can I post it here because it doesn´t work either ?

Comment: sure but please don't save the password

Comment: But otherwise I can´t log in to my account ..

Comment: just before saving it in local storage you can create a new object or use `delete` keyword before saving

Comment: I think this is not appropriate to share contact details here however if you have questions you can ask here and many people can answer to your questions

Comment: I hope you can help me on my notes section..